# Использование конфигурации проектов в Java классах, взамен XML?

Tags: java, xml, spring, config

Ну вот например:

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource("classpath:META-INF/ann-config.xml")
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = {MyController.class})
public class Initializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new 
            AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();

        ctx.register(WebConfig.class);
        ctx.setConfigLocation("classpath:META-INF/ann-config.xml");
        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(ctx));

        ctx.setServletContext(servletContext);

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = 
            servletContext.addServlet("dispather", new DispatcherServlet(ctx));
        servlet.addMapping("/");
        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    }
}
```

Собственно вопрос: 
    В чем слабые стороны такого подхода по сравнению с XML конфигурацией?
Что натолкнуло на поднятия темы? В одной компании, один из специалистов в авторитетной должности архитектора, намекнул что это считается плохим тоном. На вопрос Кем считается?  ответ Java-сообществом. Что скажете?

Comment: у каждого щас будет свое мение. мне лично удобен xml

Comment: Ну, какбы, код - это код, а конфигурация - это конфигурация (ака ресурсы). Вы же, например, не хардкодите логины с паролями внутрь кода

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду, что все таки лучше разделить - код программы 
 и конфигурация в  xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть такой термин "[hard code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_coding)" (хардкод по нашему). Мало кто будет утверждать, что это не плохо (есть варианты, когда оно нужно, но это достаточно редкие случаи).

Вот объединение конфигурации и кода - это оно и есть.

Давай рассмотрим самое очевидное - необходимость перекомпиляции после внесения изменений в конфигурацию. Потянем за ниточку, поразматываем клубок:

1. Вдруг оказалось, что для разных заказчиков нужна чуть разная конфигурация
2. Понадобилось срочно подкрутить мелочь какую-то, а разработчик в отпуске
3. Junior, которого попросили внести изменение из пункта 2 не знал, что где-то сбоку был захардкожен еще кусок конфигурации, который тоже надо было поменять, чтобы все не рухнуло. А там деплой с даунтаймами.
4. Девелоперская ветка далеко уехала от продакшена. Прям совсем далеко. И вдруг потребовалось чуток изменить конфигурацию в боевой среде. "Ээээ... А что, у нас оно не в гите разве, а в старом SVN лежало?"

и т.д.

Comment: По поводу 1 пункта: для разных заказчиков и файлы разные, будь то xml либо java. Не так ли?
По пункту 2: не поддерживается ли единый стиль в конфигурировании? Если все настроено в Java-классах, то и изменения будет Junior вносить в те самые Java-классы
В 4 пункте не понятно, причем тут гит, svn
С хардкодом и повторной компиляцией согласен, но доводы в 1-4 пунктах не очевидные, по мне

Comment: @YuriyK 1. только в одном случае вы просто меняете xml, а во втором вам под каждого заказчика делаете отдельную сборку с последующей поддержкой всего зоопарка в случае апдейтов. 2. а это на откуп кодеру("щас костыль прикручу - потом поменяю") 3. см. пункт 2. 4. это как пример того, что иногда надо править конфиги в старых сборках, что отдельная головная боль. А это и есть далеко не полный список неочевидных граблей, по которым можно начать радостно прыгать. если совсем простыми словами, то хардкод ресурсов в код - это такой хитрый способ катастрофически увеличить связность кода на пустом месте

Comment: "Радостные прыжки по граблям" улыбнуло) надо запомнить
А в общем, убедительно

Answer (score 2):

Самый главный недостаток в сравнении с xml - необходимость повторной компиляции при изменении конфигурации. А в остальном - вопрос личных предпочтений. Я люблю сочетание из аннотаций и xml.

Comment: С недостатком повторной компиляции сложно не согласиться